# Comando start com caracteres especiais (CMD)

Tags: cmd

Estou criando um arquivo em lotes que executa este comando:

```
start jogo.exe user:USUARIO pwd:SENHA
```

O comando acima faz com que um personagem entre automaticamente em um determinado jogo. O comando funciona perfeitamente se digitado através do próprio Prompt de Comando. Mas tenho que executar a mesma coisa constantemente durante o dia...

O problema é: quero criar um arquivo em lotes que execute este comando, porém quando o campo pwd:SENHA tem algum caractere especial como "**<**,**'** e **?**" o prompt diz que não existe com a seguinte mensagem:

> El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
>   "'b*5" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Desculpe, o windows do meu computador está em Espanhol.

Já percebi que o problema só ocorre quando se tem um caracter especial como < (**menor**), > (*maior*), ' (**apóstrofo**), " aspas ("**"**"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Delimite a senha com aspa dupla.
2. Escape aspa dupla com outra aspa dupla

Exemplo para a senha `a.qui<>_a_s'enha_";)_`

```
pwd:"a.qui<>_a_s'enha_"";)_"
```

Comment: obrigado, exatamente isso. Funcionou!

Comment: após alguns testes, percebi que mesmo com o comando que passou, não funciona quando a senha tem o caractere porcentagem (%), existe alguma outra forma de executar o comando? Ao executar o arquivo .bat que tem o caractere %, percebi que este caractere simplesmente some na hora da execução, ocasionando em senha incorreta.

Comment: desculpe, acabei de encontrar a solução, bastou adicionar um sinal duplo de porcentagem, ficando assim %% https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510117/5429657. Grato mesmo assim.